# How to condense this code?

Tags: java

I received some code and I am trying to put it in a better format by condensing it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    int nextInt = rand.nextInt();

    while((a.contains(nextInt) ? 1:0) + ((nextInt < 0) ? 1:0) + 
                                        ((nextInt > 1000) ? 1:0) >= 1){
        nextInt = rand.nextInt();
    }

    a.add(nextInt);

    nextInt = rand.nextInt();   

    while(((c.contains(nextInt))?1:0) + ((nextInt < 0)?1:0) +
                                        ((nextInt > 1000)?1:0) >= 1) {
        nextInt = rand.nextInt();               
    }

    c.add(nextInt); 
}
```

In the while loop there is quite the same code but I wonder if the randomness will be lost if I merge it. However the while condition seems very strange to me; can anyone explain it? How would you condense this code?

Comment: "bring it in a better format by condensing" - that's not a good approach at all. "condensing" the code will not generally make it faster (only harder to read & understand)

Comment: Make it into a method and use the method instead of writing it multiple times?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? With logic this weird (picking random numbers and then switching based on the value), it's important to encapsulate that into a method with a reasonable name. Another thing that stands out to me is that you keep calling `Array#contains` as you iterate through the loop, giving this an O(n^2) runtime. But before you optimise, consider what it is you're trying to accomplish, as there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is basically ensuring that the random number is between 0 and 1000 (both inclusive), and that it is not previously present in the list. You can optimize the range restriction by calling the `java.util.Random.nextInt(int n)` method. If your application allows you to use a `Set` instead of a `List`, you won't even need the `contains` check.

Here's how you could condense the code if you're using a `List`:

```
public void addUniqueRandom(List<Integer> list) {
    int nextInt;
    do {
        nextInt = rand.nextInt(1001);
    } while(list.contains(nextInt));

    list.add(nextInt);
}

ArrayList<Integer> a =  new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addUniqueRandom(a);
    addUniqueRandom(c);
}
```

Using `Set`s, you need to type much lesser:

```
Set<Integer> a =  new HashSet<Integer>();

Set<Integer> c = new HashSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    while (!a.add(rand.nextInt(1001))) // keep trying until we successfully add
        ;
    while (!c.add(rand.nextInt(1001)))
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The while condition is reminds me of C-style conditions where false is 0 and true is something besides 0.  However, Java has explicit booleans, so it makes more sense to use something like this for the conditional:

```
a.contains(nextInt) || (nextInt < 0) || (nextInt > 1000)
```

That code is put into a `while` loop because the code apparently needs to generate a list of unique numbers from 0 to 1000 inclusive.  If it violates any of the three conditions being "ored" then we need to generate a new random number and try again.  If it violates the first condition then it means the number is not unique, and if it violates either of the latter two conditions then it means it was not in the specified range.

I would probably place that loop in a method called `generateUniqueValueInrange` or something like that, with the list and bounds as arguments.  Also, I'm guessing that `rand` is a `java.util.Random` object.  Note that `Random` has a `nextInt(int n)` method that will generate a number within a range for you so that you don't have to keep generating new ones until they happen to fall within the bounds you want.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29

Also note that you are trying to generate two lists of 10 unique numbers from 0 to 1000.  As such, you might consider a more direct way to do exactly that.  I have personally used essentially the approach here for a similar task, but the "loop until randomness works for me" approach is error prone as it's easy to get into an infinite loop if the conditions aren't possible.

Answer (score 1):

`(a.contains(nextInt) ? 1:0) + ((nextInt < 0) ? 1:0) +  ((nextInt > 1000) ? 1:0) >= 1`-> `a.contains(nextInt) || nextInt < 0 || nextInt > 1000`

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> a =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void function(ArrayList<Integer> array){
    int nextInt = rand.nextInt();

    while((array.contains(nextInt) ? 1:0) || ((nextInt < 0) ? 1:0) ||
                                        ((nextInt > 1000) ? 1:0) >= 1){
        nextInt = rand.nextInt();
    }

    array.add(nextInt);


}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    function(a);
    function(c);
}
```

No randomness will be lost.

Comment: I agree with you; just a little improvement in the while condition: while(array.container(nextInt) || nextInt < 0 || nextInt > 1000) would be more readable.

Comment: Also, as the list size is fixed, i suggest **replacing** the `ArrayList<Integer>` with an `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want two lists with unique sets of random numbers. Here's what I would do:

```
List<Integer> a = getRandomUniqueList(10, 0, 1000);
List<Integer> b = getRandomUniqueList(10, 0, 1000);

public List<Integer> getRandomUniqueList(int count, int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        while (!set.add(min + rand.nextInt(max - min + 1))) {
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
}
```

The `Random` class already has a method to limit the range. Putting the values into a `Set` initially just makes it easy to skip duplicates. Reusing the code has no effect on the randomness. Neither does changing to this approach, although you'll get *different* random numbers if you were to use the same seed. If you *really* want better randomness then use `SecureRandom` or the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/JAVA/java.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Set (which make more sense for a collection without duplicates) you need only one loop.

```
public static Set<Integer> generate(int count, int maxValue) {
    Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while(ints.size() < count) list.add(rand.nextInt(maxValue+1)));
    return ints;
}

Set<Integer> a = generate(10, 1000); // for a set.
List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(generate(10, 1000)); // for a list.
```